# Example junit5 pact message provider test

Tags: spring, junit5, pact

I have been able to convert message consumer pact tests to junit5, but am not sure how to use the information in the junit5 provider readme to convert the corresponding message provider verification tests.  Can someone point to an example or suggest an outline of how the provider tests for message queue providers are supposed to work with the PactVerificationcontext?

I am trying to convert something like:

```
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.PactVerifyProvider;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.Consumer;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.PactRunner;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.Provider;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.loader.PactFolder;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.AmqpTarget;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.Target;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.TestTarget;


@RunWith(PactRunner.class)
@Provider("provider")
@Consumer("consumer")
@PactFolder("target/pacts")
public class MessageProviderPact {

  @TestTarget
  public final Target target = new AmqpTarget();

  private KafkaTemplate<String, MsgObject> kafkaTemplate
      = (KafkaTemplate<String, MsgObject>)Mockito.mock(KafkaTemplate.class);

  private MessageProducer messageProducer = new MessageProducer(kafkaTemplate);

  @Test
  @PactVerifyProvider("case a")
  public String verifyCaseA() throws IOException {
    // given
    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, MsgObject>> future =
        mock(ListenableFuture.class);
    doReturn(future).when(kafkaTemplate).send(any(String.class),
        any(MsgObject.class));

    // when
    DomainObj domainObj = new DomainObj();
    String topic = "kafka_add";
    messageProducer.send(topic, domainObj);

    // then
    ArgumentCaptor<MsgObject> messageCapture = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(
        MsgObject.class);
    verify(kafkaTemplate, times(1)).send(eq(topic),
        messageCapture.capture());

    // returning the message
    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(messageCapture.getValue());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the kafka template to verify the Pact message, you might have created the test Object for unit testing in order to test the Messages you can use the same test Objects. You can find the full implementation [here.](https://medium.com/@bhavesh-suvalaka/message-pact-with-junit-5-5ef773594acb)

Answer (score -1):

An example can be found in the pact-jvm [project repo](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/blob/3d56a8ab34d1233ae9abfcb3ef3a6c116d0a7575/provider/junit5/src/test/java/au/com/dius/pact/provider/junit5/AmqpContractTest.java)

The relevant code has been included below:

```
@Provider("AmqpProvider")
@PactFolder("src/test/resources/amqp_pacts")
public class AmqpContractTest {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AmqpContractTest.class);

  @TestTemplate
  @ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
  void testTemplate(Pact pact, Interaction interaction, PactVerificationContext context) {
    LOGGER.info("testTemplate called: " + pact.getProvider().getName() + ", " + interaction);
    context.verifyInteraction();
  }

  @BeforeEach
  void before(PactVerificationContext context) {
    context.setTarget(new MessageTestTarget());
  }

  @State("SomeProviderState")
  public void someProviderState() {
    LOGGER.info("SomeProviderState callback");
  }

  @PactVerifyProvider("a test message")
  public String verifyMessageForOrder() {
    return "{\"testParam1\": \"value1\",\"testParam2\": \"value2\"}";
  }

}
```

Comment: 404 when I click on that link